# lookup: select for each index contained in SheetA, its value at last date in SheetB

Tags: excel, vba

In SheetA ColumnC Line5 (up to 1000) I have one index.
In SheetB, I have large serie of lines. First column contains the index, 2nd col a date, 3rd col a value. 
I want to select for each index contained in SheetA, its value at last date in SheetB.

Answer (score 0):

Getting started in VBA can be a little daunting. Especially when you are trying to solve something that feels like it should be simple. Often times it's the things that are simple to explain that cause the biggest headaches in code.

This one isn't terribly difficult, but if you are unfamiliar with `For` Loops and how VBA references cells and range, and the various objects and variable types... it can be tricky. Below is a bit of code that should get you what you are looking for, or at least get you close.

```
Sub findValueForMaxDate()
    Dim sheetARow as Range
    Dim sheetBRow as Range
    Dim maxDate As Date
    Dim searchValue as string

    'Loop through all of the rows in SheetA
    For each sheetARow in Sheets("SheetA").Range("C5:C1000").Rows

        'Set maxdate to something really low
        maxDate = '01/01/1900'

        'While we are on each row in SheetA
        '   loop through ALL the rows in SheetB
        'Each sheetA row will cause us to loop
        '   all of the SheetB Rows
        For Each SheetBRow in Sheets("SheetB").Range("A1:A10000").Rows

            'Compare indexes and dates
            If SheetARow.Cells(1,3).Value = SheetBRow.Cells(1,1).value _
                AND SheetBRow.Cells(1,2).value > maxDate Then

                'Store this maxDate so we can compare again 
                '   if we find another index match
                maxDate = SheetBRow.Cells(1,2).value

                'Store the value from sheetBRow
                'This will be overwritten if we happen to find a
                '   higher date. 
                searchValue = SheetBRow.Cells(1,3).value
            End if
        Next SheetBRow

        'At this point the value in searchValue should be the one that corresponds
        '   to the highest date. So write it out in Column D of Sheet1 for this rows
        '   for which we are searching

        SheetARow.Cells(1,4).value = searchValue

    Next sheetARow

End Sub
```

This isn't the most efficient thing on the face of the earth since it has to loop through every sheetB row for each SheetA row. That's essentially 995*10000 loops.

A faster way would be to first sort SheetB by Index, Date descending. Then the SheetB for loop would just grab the value for the first Index found and exit the for loop. There are other ways of doing this too that are probably faster, but this is a good starting point.

In the future, when asking questions on StackOverflow, please show the code that you've written so far and let folks know exactly where you are getting stuck. Generally questions like "Show me how to write this code" are not well received and will pick up a lot of down votes. More troubleshooting here, less hand holding.

Comment: Many thanks. I will have a try tomorrow. 'keep you aware

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd offer an alternative that doesn't have nested loops, because that is a quick path to `(Not responding)` in your window caption.

This problem is much easier to approach if you recognized that you are basically wanting to do a lookup, but need to filter the values of the lookup table.  The Microsoft Scripting Runtime has a Dictionary object that can be used to build a lookup table.

Make two passes - first on SheetB to build a Dictionary that contains the row for each index with the highest date, second on SheetA to fill in the values from the Dictionary based on the indexes.

Add a reference (in the VBE Tool-->References..., then find a check it in the list) and try something like this:

```
Sub MaxValueLookup()
    Dim sheetA As Worksheet
    Dim sheetB As Worksheet
    Dim maxes As Dictionary
    Set sheetA = Sheets("SheetA")
    Set sheetB = Sheets("SheetB")
    Set maxes = New Dictionary

    'Get your lookup table:
    Dim index As Long
    Dim key As Variant
    For index = 1 To sheetB.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        key = sheetB.Cells(index, 1)
        'Check to see if you have the key already and it isn't empty.
        If key <> vbNullString Then
            If Not maxes.Exists(key) Then
                'Store the row.
                maxes.Add key, index
            Else
                'Already have it, check to see if the date is higher.
                If sheetB.Cells(index, 2) > sheetB.Cells(maxes(key), 2) Then
                    maxes(key) = index
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next index
    'Now sheetA is simple...
    For index = 5 To sheetA.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        key = sheetA.Cells(index, 1)
        If maxes.Exists(key) Then
            'Put the latest value in column B
            sheetA.Cells(index, 2) = sheetB.Cells(maxes(key), 3)
        End If
    Next index
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks. I will have a try tomorrow. 'keep you aware